# Add more applications to the Gufw drop down menu

Tags: gufw

I'm setting rules for ufw using the Gufw.

In the preconfigured tab, there are applications which I can set to allow internet access.

How can I add more applications to that list?

Answer (score 1):

gufw does not work the way you think it does. It is not an application firewall, it is a front end to ufw which in turn is a front end to iptables.

gufw is not an application level firewall, when you allow an "application" you are allowing access to your local computer.

So when you allow ssh, you are allowing connections to port 22. Apache allows port 80, etc.

In general, if you add a server, it will add to the list so you can then allow access to that service running on your local box.

So for example, I installed the squid server, now I get squid in the pull down menu

```
sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
CUPS
OpenSSH
Squid
```

You can define a service in `/etc/ufw/applications.d/`

```
ls /etc/ufw/applications.d/
squid  openssh-server  cups
```

You can define a service if you wish, the syntax is fairly stright forward. Give it an title, description, and define the port.

Using squid as an example:

```
[Squid]
title=Squid proxy cache
description=Internet object cache (WWW proxy cache)
ports=3128/tcp
```